# Python how to loop through this excel data and push it into another workbook?

Tags: python, excel, loops, openpyxl

I am currently trying to write a script that will loop through the 'members' column (see image workbook A) and copy the rows into another work book. For example 'A2 L0 - A2 L4' the corresponding rows will need to be pushed from workbook 'A' to 'B'. However the complication comes in that there are some 'members' such as 'C'5' L0 - C'5' L3'. I have no idea how I can write a script to take these values. Any suggestions how to automate this there are another 200 rows of data similar to this most are 'L0-L5'. Also I would like to reuse this said script in the future, members will always be a letter followed by a number, L0 represents lower ground L1 is first floor etc. Any help will be greatly appreciated all data was exported from a structural analysis file so it comes in the format of workbook A.[image showing data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bmpap.png)

Comment: Please take a look at this, if it helps your scenario :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71605530/possibility-of-copying-data-from-one-excel-sheet-to-another-on-a-different-colum/71608672#71608672

Comment: Please include your code in the question.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do what your question asks:

```py
import openpyxl as opxl
from openpyxl.utils.cell import coordinate_from_string, column_index_from_string
book_a = opxl.load_workbook('WORKBOOK A.xlsx', read_only=True)
book_b = opxl.load_workbook('WORKBOOK B.xlsx')
source, dest = book_a.worksheets[0], book_b.worksheets[0]

a_top_left = coordinate_from_string('P2') # returns ('P', 2)
a_left_col, a_top_row = column_index_from_string(a_top_left[0]), a_top_left[1]
a_cols = 6

b_top_left = coordinate_from_string('B42') # returns ('B', 42)
b_left_col, b_top_row = column_index_from_string(b_top_left[0]), b_top_left[1]

a_row = a_top_row
while True:
    # Clear destination area
    b_row = b_top_row
    while dest.cell(b_row, b_left_col).value != None:
        for b_col in range(b_left_col, b_left_col + a_cols):
            dest.cell(b_row, b_col).value = None
        b_row += 1

    # Copy next batch from source area to destination area
    b_row = b_top_row
    a_value = source.cell(a_row, a_left_col).value
    prev_prefix, a_prefix = None, None
    while a_value != None and a_prefix == prev_prefix:
        for a_col, b_col in zip(range(a_left_col, a_left_col + a_cols), range(b_left_col, b_left_col + a_cols)):
            dest.cell(b_row, b_col).value = source.cell(a_row, a_col).value
        if prev_prefix == None:
            prev_prefix = str(a_value).split()[0]
        a_row, b_row = a_row + 1, b_row + 1
        a_value = source.cell(a_row, a_left_col).value
        if a_value != None:
            a_prefix = str(a_value).split()[0]
    print(f"A batch of members rows with prefix {prev_prefix} has been copied to the destination")
    book_b.save(f"WORKBOOK B prefix {prev_prefix}.xlsx")
    if a_value == None:
        break
```

I'm not sure what processing you want to do after loading in a batch of member rows with a given prefix (the 6 rows with prefix 'A2', or the 5 rows with prefix 'B3', etc.). The example code above saves a new copy of WORKBOOK B for each batch, but you can change this as needed.

Comment: @popo.dior Did this answer work for you? Do you need any additional help?