# Updates excel file, Vlookup, DataFrame and Python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl

I'm a beginner in Python, openpyxl and pandas.
Hopefully some expert can help me to figure out how to create a code to update track2.

```
    Track 1
ID   Values
A     JK2L
B     IIKL
C     OIP2
...
```

ID column may have thousand row in it.

for Track 2

```
Track 2
        ID   Values
        A     
        B     
        C
....
```

Track 1 is save in different excel file name same goes with the Track 2.
Track 1 is keep on updating everyday, for track 2 to be aligned with Track 1. The Track 2 will get the data from the Track 1 to updates the file name of Track 2 using the Vlookup method.

It is possible to create a code from python to update the Track 2?
What I have in mind is this code:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_excel('Track 1.xlsx', sheet_name = 'Delivery')
df2 = pd.read_excel('Track 2.xlsx', sheet_name ='Owner')
.....
```

Then I'm stock don't know how to write next code.

Comment: Please provide more structured (step by step) details. What do you want to achive? Vlookup to rename the file??

Comment: It is more on vlookup in excel getting information as per ID to be able to align the Track 2 with Track 1. Take note, Track 1 and Track are in different file name. just what I did in the Dataframe of df1 and df2.

Comment: Please see if this helps your scenario:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71605530/possibility-of-copying-data-from-one-excel-sheet-to-another-on-a-different-colum/71608672#71608672

You will need to create two different file objects since you have two different files and use them accordingly to read data from one and write data to another